# How to design a certain period of a month

Tags: php

An user selects a specific month.
A function searches and designs a specific period.
e.g.
FROM the first day of month TO saturday
sunday - saturday
Until the final week.
sunday - the last day of month

e.g.

When the Parameter is 2022-11
Then

```
2022-11-01  - 2022-11-05
2022-11-06  - 2022-11-12
...
2022-11-27  -2022-11-30
```

Hoever ,  my code does not work correctly.
How should I fix it?

I think

```
date($arraySaturdayList[$k], strtotime("+1 day")
```

seems not work well.

```
private function month($start_date,$end_datel,holidays,
    {
            $arraySaturdayList = $this->makeSaturDayList($start_date,$end_date);

/*
$arraySaturdayList  = Array
(
    [0] => 2022-11-05
    [1] => 2022-11-12
    [2] => 2022-11-19
    [3] => 2022-11-26
)
*/

            for($i = $start_date,$k=0;  $i <= $end_date ;$i++)
            {
           
                if($k+1 > sizeof($arraySaturdayList))
                {
                     break;
                }
         
                    
                       $previousSunday  = "";
                       $nextSunday = date($arraySaturdayList[$k], strtotime("+1 day"));
                       if($k > 0){
                        $previousSunday = date($arraySaturdayList[$k-1], strtotime("+1 day"));
                       }
                       
                                              }
                       //2nd week~　NOT the final
                       else if($k < sizeof($arraySaturdayList)){
//start_date should start from sunday . end_date should be ended in saturday.
$this->assignByWeekRange($previousSunday,$arraySaturdayList[$k]);
                       }
                       //the last week. (start from sunday end should be the last day of a month.)
                       else{
                                   $this->assignByWeekRange($previousSunday,$end_date);
                       }
                    $k++;
                }
            
            }
```

The result was

```
S=2022-11-01E=2022-11-05  
S=2022-11-05E=2022-11-12  
S=2022-11-12E=2022-11-19  
S=2022-11-19E=2022-11-26
```

Comment: I suggest to use CRON job for this kind of script

Comment: It is not a funtion that runs regularly

Comment: What does this list of dates you have given - _"2022-11-01 - 2022-11-05 2022-11-06 - 2022-11-12 ... 2022-11-27 -2022-11-30"_ - have to do with "every week"? Those do not look like they were all a week apart.

Comment: I would like to make this
It is FROM the first day of month TO saturday monday - saturday Until the final week. sunday - the last day of month.
*the first day week starts from sunday in this function.

Comment: @user2006734 I posted an answer with another solution.

Comment: @user2006734 Did my answer help you? Mark it as accepted please if it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

**Put the following codes into defined files and test them.**

**`expectedWeeks.php`**

```php
<?php

$weeksByMonths = [
    "01" => [
        "2022-01-01 - 2022-01-01",
        "2022-01-02 - 2022-01-08",
        "2022-01-09 - 2022-01-15",
        "2022-01-16 - 2022-01-22",
        "2022-01-23 - 2022-01-29",
        "2022-01-30 - 2022-01-31"
    ],
    "02" => [
        "2022-02-01 - 2022-02-05",
        "2022-02-06 - 2022-02-12",
        "2022-02-13 - 2022-02-19",
        "2022-02-20 - 2022-02-26",
        "2022-02-27 - 2022-02-28"
    ],
    "03" => [
        "2022-03-01 - 2022-03-05",
        "2022-03-06 - 2022-03-12",
        "2022-03-13 - 2022-03-19",
        "2022-03-20 - 2022-03-26",
        "2022-03-27 - 2022-03-31"
    ],
    "04" => [
        "2022-04-01 - 2022-04-02",
        "2022-04-03 - 2022-04-09",
        "2022-04-10 - 2022-04-16",
        "2022-04-17 - 2022-04-23",
        "2022-04-24 - 2022-04-30"
        // ,"2022-05-01 - 2022-04-30"
    ],
    "05" => [
        "2022-05-01 - 2022-05-07",
        "2022-05-08 - 2022-05-14",
        "2022-05-15 - 2022-05-21",
        "2022-05-22 - 2022-05-28",
        "2022-05-29 - 2022-05-31"
    ],
    "06" => [
        "2022-06-01 - 2022-06-04",
        "2022-06-05 - 2022-06-11",
        "2022-06-12 - 2022-06-18",
        "2022-06-19 - 2022-06-25",
        "2022-06-26 - 2022-06-30"
    ],
    "07" => [
        "2022-07-01 - 2022-07-02",
        "2022-07-03 - 2022-07-09",
        "2022-07-10 - 2022-07-16",
        "2022-07-17 - 2022-07-23",
        "2022-07-24 - 2022-07-30",
        "2022-07-31 - 2022-07-31"
    ],
    "08" => [
        "2022-08-01 - 2022-08-06",
        "2022-08-07 - 2022-08-13",
        "2022-08-14 - 2022-08-20",
        "2022-08-21 - 2022-08-27",
        "2022-08-28 - 2022-08-31"
    ],
    "09" => [
        "2022-09-01 - 2022-09-03",
        "2022-09-04 - 2022-09-10",
        "2022-09-11 - 2022-09-17",
        "2022-09-18 - 2022-09-24",
        "2022-09-25 - 2022-09-30"
    ],
    "10" => [
        "2022-10-01 - 2022-10-01",
        "2022-10-02 - 2022-10-08",
        "2022-10-09 - 2022-10-15",
        "2022-10-16 - 2022-10-22",
        "2022-10-23 - 2022-10-29",
        "2022-10-30 - 2022-10-31"
    ],
    "11" => [
        "2022-11-01 - 2022-11-05",
        "2022-11-06 - 2022-11-12",
        "2022-11-13 - 2022-11-19",
        "2022-11-20 - 2022-11-26",
        "2022-11-27 - 2022-11-30"
    ],
    "12" => [
        "2022-12-01 - 2022-12-03",
        "2022-12-04 - 2022-12-10",
        "2022-12-11 - 2022-12-17",
        "2022-12-18 - 2022-12-24",
        "2022-12-25 - 2022-12-31"
        //,"2023-01-01 - 2022-12-31"
    ],
];
```

`helperFunctions.php`

```php
<?php

function printList($list)
{
    echo "\n\n";
    foreach($list as $entry)
    {
        echo "\n". implode(" - ", $entry);
    }
}


function compareResult($expected, $generated)
{
    if(count($expected) != count($generated))
    {
        echo "\n\nERROR: The number of generated ranges differ from expected one";
        print_r($expected);
        printList($generated);
        return;
    }
    foreach($generated as $i => $entry)
    {
        if($expected[$i] != implode(" - ", $entry))
        {
            echo "\n\nERROR: The generated range $entry differs from the expected one: " . $expected[$i];
            print_r($expected);
            printList($generated);
            return;
        }
    }
    echo "\n\nSUCCESS: Generated ranges equal to expected ones.";
}
```

**And finally the main script `main.php` which contains the functions, which generate the ranges.**

```php
<?php
include "expectedWeeks.php";
include "helperFunctions.php";
define("DAY_SECONDS" , 86400);
define("LOG_STEPS_TO_CONSOLE" , true);

/**
 * string $yearMonth Month "2022-11
 *
 */
function getAllSaturdays($yearMonth, $asDate = false)
{
    $time = strtotime($yearMonth);
    $month = intval(date("n", $time));
    $currentMonth = $month;
    $saturdays = [];
    while($currentMonth == $month)
    {
        if(date("D", $time) == "Sat")
        {
            $saturdays[] = $asDate ? date("Y-m-d", $time) : $time;
        }
        $time += DAY_SECONDS;
        $currentMonth = intval(date("n", $time));
    }
    return $saturdays;
}

/**
 * Generates a list of ranges, which start with Sunday and end with Saturday by default,
 * otherwise starts with the first day and/or resp. ends with last day of the montch of the month.
 *
 */
function generateWeeksEndWithSaturday($yearMonth)
{
    $list = [];
    if(LOG_STEPS_TO_CONSOLE) echo "\n\nMONTH: " . date("F", strtotime($yearMonth));
    $saturdays = getAllSaturdays($yearMonth);
    $nDaysInMonth = date("t", strtotime($yearMonth));
    foreach($saturdays as $saturdayTime)
    {
        $saturdayTime += 43200;// midday time for correct calculation on time shifting days
        $day = intval(date("j", $saturdayTime));
        $saturDate =  date("Y-m-d", $saturdayTime);
        if(LOG_STEPS_TO_CONSOLE) echo "\n\nSATURDAY : " . $saturDate;

        # This Saturday is the first day of the month
        if($day == 1)
        {
            if(LOG_STEPS_TO_CONSOLE) echo "\nFirst day of the month";
            $list[] = [$saturDate, $saturDate];
            if(LOG_STEPS_TO_CONSOLE) echo "\nAdding: " .  implode(":", $list[array_key_last($list)]);
        }
        # This Saturday is the 6th day of the month
        else if($day < 7)
        {
            if(LOG_STEPS_TO_CONSOLE) echo "\t-->\tWithin the first 6 days";
            $from = date("Y-m-d", $saturdayTime - (($day-1) * DAY_SECONDS));
            $list[] = [$from, $saturDate];
            if(LOG_STEPS_TO_CONSOLE) echo "\nAdding: " .  implode(" - ", $list[array_key_last($list)]);
        }
        #
        elseif($day+7 > $nDaysInMonth)
        {
            if(LOG_STEPS_TO_CONSOLE) echo "\t-->\tThe last saturday in the month";

            // current week
            $from = date("Y-m-d", $saturdayTime - (6*DAY_SECONDS));
            // $from = date("Y-m-d", $saturdayTime - (6*86400));
            $list[] = [$from, $saturDate ];

            if(LOG_STEPS_TO_CONSOLE) echo "\nAdding: " .  implode(" - ", $list[array_key_last($list)]);

            # The rest of the month
            if($day < $nDaysInMonth)
            {
                $n = $nDaysInMonth - $day;
                $from =  date("Y-m-d", $saturdayTime + DAY_SECONDS);
                $to =  date("Y-m-d", $saturdayTime + ($n*DAY_SECONDS));
                $list[] = [$from, $to];
                if(LOG_STEPS_TO_CONSOLE) echo "\nAdding the rest of the month: " .  implode(" - ", $list[array_key_last($list)]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(LOG_STEPS_TO_CONSOLE) echo "\t-->\tNormal";
            $from = date("Y-m-d", $saturdayTime - (6*DAY_SECONDS));
            $list[] = [$from, $saturDate];
            if(LOG_STEPS_TO_CONSOLE) echo "\nAdding: " .  implode(" - ", $list[array_key_last($list)]);
        }
    }
    return $list;
}



// Month hard coded
$month = "11";
// Pass the month as parameter. For example: php weeks.php 11
$month = $argv[1];

compareResult($weeksByMonths[$month], generateWeeksEndWithSaturday("2022-$month"));
```

**Then you can execute it in the console like this for May:**

```bash
php main.php 05
```

**You should the the output:**

[image]

**GENERIC METHOD FOR ALL WEEK DAYS**

You can rename the function `getAllSaturdays()` to a generic one and use it for all week days as ending day in a range:

```php
function getAllDatesForWeekdayInAMonth($yearMonth, $weekDay, $asDate = false)
{
    $time = strtotime($yearMonth);
    $month = intval(date("n", $time));
    $currentMonth = $month;
    $days = [];
    while($currentMonth == $month)
    {
        if(date("D", $time) == $weekDay)
        {
            $days[] = $asDate ? date("Y-m-d", $time) : $time;
        }
        $time += DAY_SECONDS;
        $currentMonth = intval(date("n", $time));
    }
    return $days;
}
```